# How to invert a matrix plus a Kronecker product pre and post multiplied by another matrix?

Tags: optimization, matrix-calculus, matrix-decomposition, multivariate-statistical-analysis

For my optimization algorithm, I need to invert a matrix- 
$V = \Sigma + U^\prime (R \otimes D) U $  where  $\Sigma = diag(\Sigma_0, \ldots, \Sigma_k), D = diag(D_0, \ldots, D_0)$ are block-diagonal matrices. R is a symmetric positive definite matrix. U is a rectangular matrix. 
Is there an efficient way to calculate $V^{-1}$? Helps are much appreciated!

Comment: Why do you "need" to invert `V`? What will you do with that inverse? Do you really just need to solve some equations involving `V`?

Comment: Yes. Thanks for your query! For optimizing the likelihood, I need to invert V to solve a system of multiple equations.